# Is a Polish bluecard transferable to Germany (and other EU countries)?

Tags: blue-card

Let's say I have bluecard from Poland and am currently working in Poland (non-EU IT professional).

Now, if I get a job offer from Germany (or any other EU member) or if I'm laid off/fired from the Polish job and have to go out looking for a job.

Would I be able to just transfer the Poland bluecard to the German employer?

Or will it require the German employer to sponsor a brand new bluecard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two benefits of the Blue card that are intended to make moving between countries easier: You can move first and apply within a month (as opposed to waiting out the whole procedure before taking up employment) and periods of residence accrued in different member states count towards the five-year threshold for permanent resident status.

Apart from that, you must basically apply for a fresh EU blue card. It is still required to meet all the requirements and the procedure to get your foreign education recognised in Germany is somewhat cumbersome. Your employer does not need to “sponsor” you *per se* but you must in any case have a job or job offer before you apply and that job must meet the minimum salary requirement.

Comment: Thank you. Just so I understand it clearly, a Poland temporary residence permit will not have those two benefits?

Comment: @Achilles Yes, that's correct.